# Android - Wrap buttons within view

Tags: android, android-button

I am trying to make buttons wrap in a LinearLayout in Android, but they are just continuing off to the right of the view (the word shown in the screenshot should be "HELLO", so I want the "O" to drop down to the next line).

[image]

I am adding the buttons programmatically, but even if I code them into the XML layout file, they still don't wrap. Here is the layout file with the LinearLayout container into which I am dynamically adding the buttons:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    tools:context=".LetterTileView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TilesContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code I am using to create and add the tile buttons:

```
Context context = this;
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.TilesContainer);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    params.setMargins(50, 50, 0, 0);
    for (int i=0;i<wordLength;i++) {
        Button tileButton = new Button(this);
        tileButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        tileButton.setText(wordStringtoLetters[i]);
        tileButton.setId(i);
        tileButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tile_button);
        tileButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 36);
        layout.addView(tileButton);
    }
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Since you're already using a ConstraintLayout, why not consider ___Flow___ https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow - https://proandroiddev.com/awesomeness-of-constraintlayout-flow-aa0b5edd5df

Comment: Thanks, Nikos, I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using FlexboxLayout, which works great for this. Thanks to those who offered suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to use a *ConstraintLayout* you can use your *LinearLayout* as the parent layout.

Then for the purpose of displaying all buttons in one line, you have to set weight for the *LinearLayout* in XML and set weight for the views you add to it.

The xml file should look like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/TilesContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

And in code you should set weight for each view you by adding **,1.0f** to LayoutParam :

```
 Context context = this;
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.TilesContainer);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f );
params.setMargins(50, 50, 0, 0);
for (int i=0;i<wordLength;i++) {
    Button tileButton = new Button(this);
    tileButton.setLayoutParams(params);
    tileButton.setText(wordStringtoLetters[i]);
    tileButton.setId(i);
    tileButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tile_button);
    tileButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 36);
    layout.addView(tileButton);
}
```